# Query joins on 3 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I apologize for not knowing the correct terminology for what I'm trying to do.  I can't paste exact code because I have an air gap and my working system is not on the internet so I will pseudo code here.

I have two tables, lets call them TopDogs and BottomDogs.  I need a query that returns results from TopDogs that don't match 3 of the columns of Bottom Dogs.  Lets say TopDogs has columns A, B, C, D, E, F and G.  BottomDogs has A, B, C, M, Q, R, S

I need a query that will return a list of all the rows of TopDogs that don't match BottomDogs A, B, and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TopDogs td
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   BottomDogs bd
                   WHERE  td.a = bd.a AND td.b = bd.b AND td.c = bd.c)
```